# How to override a pure virtual function in template class in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to override a pure virtual function:

```
template <class P, class R> class Visitor {
    public:
        virtual ~Visitor() {}
        virtual R visit(ASTNode& n, P p) = 0;
};

class ToStringVisitor : public Visitor<string, int> {
    virtual string visit(ASTNode& n, int p) override {
        return "";
    }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: 'virtual std::__cxx11::string ToStringVisitor::visit(ASTNode&, int)' marked 'override', but does not override
  virtual string visit(ASTNode& n, int p) override {
```

Why isn't this overriding?

None of the other questions I could find on SO have such a succinct example, or the detail of a template return value in the superclass.

Comment: `virtual int visit(ASTNode& n, string p) override` or change `Visitor<int, string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
class ToStringVisitor : public Visitor<string, int> {
                     parameter type (P) --^     ^-- return type (R)
```

you have to swap `string` with `int` because it mismatches the parameter that should be passed (`P = int`) and the return type (`R = string`):

```
class ToStringVisitor : public Visitor<int, string> {
                   parameter type (P) --^      ^-- return type (R)
```

then it will be conform with the template class declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The return type of the method is declared `R` and in your case this means `int`, not `string`.